# Mapping csv columns to composite Pojo classes

Tags: csv, mapping, pojo, univocity

I am using univocity-parser library for this

class Person{

@Parsed(index=1)

String name;

@Parsed(index=2)

String age;

Address address;

}

class Address{

@Parsed(index=3)

String street;

String city;

}

BeanListProcessor rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor(Person.class);

List beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();

Exception while mapping the csv columns to POJO class :
com.univocity.parsers.common.DataProcessingException: Unable to set value to address field

Is there any other way to do it

Comment: Hi, please see the [help] to learn how to format your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@Nested` annotation introduced in version 2.4.0, just do this:

```
class Person{
    @Parsed(index=1)
    String name;

    @Parsed(index=2)
    String age;

    @Nested
    Address address;
}
```